# Using hasClass() with jQuery delegate?

Tags: jquery, delegates

I have a gridview (gdvMyInfo) that contains q column of links I have grabbing with jQuery.

```
$('#<%= gdvMyInfo.ClientID %>').delegate('a', 'click', function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    ....
    return false;
});
```

This was working great, but now there will be a second column containing links and I need to turn on paging. This is now attaching my jQuery changes to these new links.

I have a class of "myInfoClass" on the links I need but using the class as the selector does not seem to work for me (not sure if it is the delegate as without that it selects fine).

```
$('.myInfoClass').delegate('a', 'click', function(){
```

this does not work, so I was thinking I could use the .hasClass() function but that is failing also.

```
$('#<%= gdvMyInfo.ClientID %>').hasClass('myInfoClass').delegate('a', 'click', function(){
```

This fails with a error message of ".delegate is not a function"

So, any idea on how I can chain a selector using delegate to grab any `<a>` in my gridvie "gdvMyIfno" with a class of "myInfoClass" when using a delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the class to the selector:

```
$('#<%= gdvMyInfo.ClientID %>').delegate('a.myInfoClass', 'click', function(){
```

Now the `click` will only fire for `<a>` elements that have the class `myInfoClass`.

The way `.delegate()` works is that it places a handler on the container `#<%= gdvMyInfo.ClientID %>`. Then elements clicked inside that container get compared to the `a.myInfoClass` selector. If the element matches the selector, the handler is invoked.

Comment: Thank you. This is the first time I have used delegate so I am still learning about how it works. This is great.

Comment: @zk + hasClass() returns 'true' or 'false', you can't chain it like you do with methods that return jquery object.

Comment: @tsiokos: Oh thanks, that would explain the error I was getting.